# symbol "-" not shown in any of "listings" after compiling together with "breqn" package

Tags: listings, incompatibility, breqn

After compiling my "-" symbol in every single listing environment dissapears. I found out that "listings" package must somehow conflict with "breqn" package. Below is a minimal working example. Try to coment/uncomment `\usepackage{breqn}` and then compile.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openany]{report}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{breqn}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
arm-none-eabi-as -mcpu=arm926ej-s -c -Wall -ostartup.o startup.s
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

I would really love to use both, but only if anyone can tell me, why i get this bug and how can it be fixed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could locally reset - in listings like so, if no better way is suggested:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openany]{report}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}

%fix for \begin{lstlisting}
\edef\savedmiuscode{\mathcode`\noexpand\-\the\mathcode`\-\relax}
\let\oldlstlisting\lstlisting
%\show\savedmiuscode
\def\lstlisting{\savedmiuscode\oldlstlisting}

%fix for \lstinputlisting{}    
\edef\savedmiuscode{\mathcode`\noexpand\-\the\mathcode`\-\relax}
\let\oldlstinputlisting\lstinputlisting
%\show\savedmiuscode
\def\lstinputlisting{\savedmiuscode\oldlstinputlisting}

\usepackage{breqn}



\begin{document}



\begin{lstlisting}
arm-none-eabi-as -mcpu=arm926ej-s -c -Wall -ostartup.o startup.s
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: For the final solution, you might want to remove `\show\savedmiuscode`. `:-)`

Comment: @diabonas  ah edited answer, thanks:-)